# Automapper exception : must resolve to top-level member

Tags: c#, automapper

How to map following ItemId (as Source) with DataId (as Output):

Source:

```
public class Source
{
    public InputData InputItem { get; set; }
}
public class InputData
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
public class Output
{
    public List<OutputData> OutputItem { get; set; }
}
public class OutputData
{
    public string[] DataID { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to map it in following way:

```
CreateMap<Source, Output>().ForMember(d => d.OutputItem[0].DataID,
   option => option.MapFrom(s => s.InputItem != null ? new string[] { $"item_{s.InputItem.ItemID}" } : null));
```

Getting the exception:

> Expression 'd => d.OutputItem.get_Item(0).DataID' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead. Parameter name: lambdaExpression

Can someone please help me in mapping these objects.

Thanks

Comment: Yes but not working with CustomTypeConverter as well.

Answer (score 1):

The error basically says that you can only define a mapping for one level of the object. You can not define the mapping to directly write to a property of a child object.

Solve this by defining separate mappings for the objects on each level.

First define the mapping for the child objects:

```
CreateMap<InputData, OutputData>().ForMember(d => d.DataID,
       option => option.MapFrom(s => s != null ? new string[] { $"item_{s.ItemID}" } : null));
```

Then the mapping for the parent object can use this definition to map its child objects. (Collections like `List<OutputData>` should be filled by AutoMapper automatically.)

```
CreateMap<Source, Output>().ForMember(d => d.OutputItem,
       option => option.MapFrom(s => s.InputItem));
```

Comment: OP has `List<OutputData>` inside `Output` . This will still give error Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping between `InputData` and `List<OutputData>`

Comment: I did not try the mapping I gave above, but as far as I remember automapper should add items to lists automatically if it knows how to map the objects contained in the collections.

Comment: If both source and destinations were collections it will work. However I doubt in this particular scenario.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider
Getting the following exception:

**Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.**

Mapping types:
Char -> OutputData
System.Char -> Models.OutputData

Comment: This is the stacktrace

 `at lambda_method(Closure , Char , OutputData, ResolutionContext )

 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Output , ResolutionContext )`